# What is wrong with the structure of this nested query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, nested

I am using `SQL Server 2014` and I have the following `T-SQL` query:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT (xx.[Email]), xx.[StayID] 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         COUNT (x.[RepID]),x.[StayID], x.[Email], x.[RepID]
     FROM
         (SELECT 
              *, 
              ([Email] + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [Arrival Date], 20)) AS 'RepID' 
          FROM [Table1]
          WHERE [Arrival Date] BETWEEN '2015-07-01' AND '2018-06-30'
            AND [Email] <> '') x
    GROUP BY 
        x.[StayID], x.[Email], x.[RepID]
    HAVING
        COUNT(x.[RepID]) > 1) xx
GROUP BY 
    xx.[StayID], xx.[Email]
HAVING 
    COUNT(xx.[Email]) > 1
```

I am getting the following error message:

> No column name was specified for column 1 of 'xx'.

What am I doing wrong here?

I was also looking at changing the query into a `CTE`. Would that be a solution?

Comment: What part of the error message is *unclear*? It's telling you - column one of the `xx` subquery hasn't been given a name. Since you're apparently not attempting to refer to that column outside of the subquery at all, why does it even exist?

Comment: That would have worked in some RDBMS but not in SQL server. You have to name the columns inside a subquery (`COUNT(x.[RepID]) AS foo`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this - Modified your query and given the name to xx first column (RepIdCount):

```
SELECT COUNT (xx.[Email]), xx.[StayID]
FROM (    
  SELECT COUNT (x.[RepID]) as RepIDCount, x.[StayID], x.[Email], x.[RepID]
  FROM (
    SELECT *, ([Email] + CONVERT(varchar(10), [Arrival Date], 20)) as 'RepID' 
    FROM [Table1]
    WHERE [Arrival Date] between '2015-07-01' and '2018-06-30'
    AND [Email] <> ''
  ) x
  GROUP BY x.[StayID], x.[Email], x.[RepID]
  Having Count(x.[RepID]) > 1
) xx
GROUP BY xx.[StayID], xx.[Email]
Having Count(xx.[Email]) >  1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say you rewrite the query in a better way, but the issue in your query is in the below line

```
SELECT COUNT (x.[RepID]), x.[StayID], x.[Email], x.[RepID]
```

you either remove the **COUNT (x.[RepID])** statement since its not used in your parent Select statement or you an give an alias like below

```
SELECT COUNT (x.[RepID]) as RepCount, x.[StayID], x.[Email], x.[RepID]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run this simple query:

```
select count(*) from some_table
```

you will notice the result set in the output will have a column name of "No column name".

SQL server does not generate a default column name for aggregate functions.
Thus, the first (and only) column of table xx, i.e.

`COUNT (x.[RepID]),x.[StayID], x.[Email], x.[RepID]`

has no name. You may not have a subquery that included unnamed columns. give it a name:

```
 COUNT (x.[RepID]) as cnt ,x.[StayID], x.[Email], x.[RepID])
```

By the way, why go in the trouble of typing all the column names in the `COUNT`?

1. Could it be you